# How to export latitude and longitude values of each pixel corner?

Tags: envi, idl

I want to extract latitude and longitude values for each pixel's corner of a TIFF image. The latitude and longitude values for the top right and top left are known.
How should I perform this task in ENVI or IDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of fancy software like ENVI or IDL

If the tiff files have an accompanying .tfw file (a.k.a. world file), you can open that file in a text editor and all the information you need is there. The coordinates of the center of the upper left pixel are in the 5th and 6th line, the size of the pixels in the 1st and 4th lines. With this values you can easily calculate the coordinates of the center of any pixel. [Here is more info on the world file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file).

If  you have no .tfw file you can create it extracting the info from the tiff file header using a small utility like [GeoTiff examiner](https://www.mediafire.com/file/a3hv2q9bchez8u8/geotiffexaminer.exe)

You can also edit the tfw file and/or the headers (using that utility) to fix the shift you are experiencing.